# Что значит среда с невытесняющей многозадачностью?

Tags: многопоточность, терминология

Что значит среда с невытесняющей многозадачностью?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При не вытесняющая многозадачности задача (поток) должен сам периодически отдавать управление монитору (ос) чтобы управление передали другим задачам. Если задача зациклится в коде, не обращающемся к монитору, то ее никто не прервет и все остальные будут ждать.

В отличие от нее при вытесняющей многозадачности монитор сам прервет выполнение долго работающей программы без ее ведома и передаст управление другой.

Answer (score -1):

Если процесс занял процессор в среде с *невытесняющий многозадачностью*, то, пока он не закончится, операционная система не даст ни кванта времени на выполнение какого-либо другого процесса

Comment: Это вообще без многозадачности.

Comment: Есть многозадачность. Просто другие задачи ждут завершения выполнения текущей задачи. Процесс, который захватил процессор может со своего согласия отдать время другому процессу, ожидающему в очереди.

Comment: Задача - это не процесс. А про "может отдать" должно быть в ответе.

Comment: Потому что может и не отдать. Вот и невытесняющая поэтому, а все остальное уже частные случаи. В данном контексте задача и процесс - слова синонимы.